# strip part of and add directory tof the url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just wondering how I can rewrite this

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg&h=&w=240&zc=1
```

into this

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg
```

using .htaccess.

combine

Stripping for the last part is not so difficult, but how to combine it with adding the directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` file and place this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/

RewriteRule ^(.+?)&.*$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said and thought it would work because it is such a simple solution, but it doesn't rewrite. Other rewrites in the root htaccess do work though. What could be a reason it doesn't rewrite. Thanks

Comment: Does `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` already have any rules? If yes then post them here. Also is `/wp-content/uploads/` present in 2 places now?

Comment: I have .htaccess in the root. Then there is .htaccess in the dir wordpress (where WordPress is installed). I created the dir wp-content/uploads in the root, since it didn't excist and added your .htaccess there. In the wordpress dir there is wp-content/uploads with no .htaccess file. I scanned all files for the word 'content' but non of them has. Except the one in your lines.

Comment: So path of image file from document root is `/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/` instead of `/wp-content/uploads/` ?

Comment: The path to the old image (which is not in the uploads folder anymore) is /wp-content/uploads/. Path to the new image is /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/

Comment: But both `DocumentRoot/wp-content/uploads/` and `DocumentRoot/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/` directories exist?

Comment: Try updated rule now. Though previous one should have worked also

Comment: With the update, the rewrite to the wordpress dir works only the removal of &h=&w=240&zc=1 not yet. Thanks so far though.

Comment: This one works, but is it good code? RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpg&h=&w=240&zc=1 /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/$1.jpg? [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: My suggested rule will strip of any pre existing query string from original uri. I think that's what you wanted right?

Comment: Yes I wanted to remove &h=&w=240&zc=1, but with you rule above it stayed.

Comment: No it doesn't stay since I have `?` at the end of target URI `/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/$1?` Make sure you test it in a different browser to avoid old 301 caching.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried in all big browsers but with all of them &h=&w=240&zc=1 stayed. Maybe an ampersand is not the same as query?